# How to Link 2 executable Projects in Visual Stduio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am making a Game Engine which consists of 2 projects:

1. The editor project
2. The game project

In the editor project on behalf normal functions(add object,add player), there is a function called gameloop which has player movement etc. and it needs to be called from `int main` in the game project in order to create a "Game" executable.
I included the headers from 1. project. and I tried to build the 2. project and... unresolved external symbol in gameloop function.
How can I solve this ?
Note: Both projects' target must be exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I solve this ? Note: Both projects' target must be exe.

Separate out the common code of these two projects to a static or dynamically linkable library project, and refer to that one from both projects.

Comment: Isn't there any other solution? the 2. project has just 14 lines of code in 1 file and I don't want to reshape my whole projects if I don't have to

Comment: @StelTeam No, there isn't any other solution, you can't link anything from another executable to your current one. You might simply share the relevant translation units maybe. But the usual way is to have a library with the commonly used code. This would also give you the advantage to easily automate unit-testing your common code in even an other project setup for a test runner.

Comment: What type of code should I put into the Library project? headers or .cpp files ?

Comment: @StelTeam A library is usually constituted by translation units (i.e. `.cpp` files). Headers allow other projects to bind (link) properly with these. The library itself of course needs to see the header files as well for consitency.